What is political bias?
People often claim that certain news reports or other forms of content either do or do not have "political bias".
Lots of content is related to politics in one way or another. What makes content "politically biased", and why should the audience care?

This can be answered with a simple Google search

Doesn't this reduce to "what is bias"?

@keshlam yeah in hindsight that probably would've been a better question!

Media bias is a tendency to present one set of viewpoints more often and/or more strongly than other viewpoints.
For media outlets, I see at least three types of bias:

Coverage bias: The choice of what stories to cover.
Source bias: The choice of what sources to use/interview.
Interpretation bias: The conclusions drawn or implied by the journalists.

So, for example Fox News will tend to cover topics more important to their conservative viewers, cite sources and interview people that are conservative, and will present analysis/opinions that apply a conservative lens to the facts.
Same thing for something like MSNBC, but the opposite (politically).
Bias in itself isn't bad unless it distorts the facts. We all bring a perspective and different interests, and these will inevitably color our views.
Also, some "bias" is good -- like the bias against conspiracy theories.

Is there such a thing as "absolute" bias or "absolute" neutrality? I can see that, relatively speaking, Fox is biased in a conservative direction compared to MSNBC, but is there some sort of political neutrality those two examples can be compared to? Or is bias meant to be a purely relative measure?

@ChristopherKing I’m not aware of any definition of absolute bias/neutrality.
